# Algorithm to fade elements nicely within 100% height div

Tags: jquery, algorithm

Using jQuery I have a div set at 100% width and height. They have some elements in the middle which are centred vertically and horizontally using jQuery. When the website is scrolled I want the inner elements to fade out nicely, but I cant work out a good algorithm.

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-inner">
        <h1>Site</h1>
        <h2>Slogan</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am thinking maybe I need to get the outerHeight() of the header and do something there. So:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('#header-inner').css({'opacity': 100 ??? });
});
```

Fiddle is here:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69heq1zg/)

Comment: Can you post an example? Do you have any reference of the desired behavior?

Comment: Why not just use a jQuery-UI transition?

Comment: I want it to fade out gradually as it goes up the page which I am thinking would be calculated by the height of the div. Everything I have tried fades it out a bit too quickly.

Comment: Added a Fiddle to help

Comment: Did you try associating opacity with the speed or acceleration of the scroll, or a combination of both position and speed?

Comment: Another idea might be to completely regulate the opacity to your liking by, for example, creating a look-up table that directs scrollTop to the exact opacity you'd like at that point.